# Adding objects of different types in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, extend

I have a couple of questions about this code:

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String _args[]) {
    // this is a reference variable of type Truck, referring
    // an object of type Truck
    Truck _firstTruck = new Truck("Volvo", "Generic", "blue", 8000, 20);

    // this is a reference variable of type Vehicle, referring
    // an object of type Vehicle
    Vehicle _firstVehicle = new Vehicle("Bicycle", "red");

    // since a Truck is also a Vehicle, we can have 
    // a reference variable of type Vehicle, referring
    // an object of type Truck
    Vehicle _secondVehicle = new Truck("Scania", "unknown", "green", 7000, 30);

    //better yet, we can do this:
    Vehicle _vehicles[] = new Vehicle[3];
    _vehicles[0] = _firstTruck; // a truck is a vehicle
    _vehicles[1] = _firstVehicle;
    _vehicles[2] = _secondVehicle;

    for (int i = 0; i < _vehicles.length; i++) {
        _vehicles[i].increaseSpeedBy();
    }

}
```

}

I understand that the Array _vehicles[] is of type Vehicle and thus I am not able to add a Truck object into the array, right?

```
 _vehicles[1] = _firstVehicle;
 _vehicles[2] = _secondVehicle;
```

Those two are ok because they are of the same type(Vehicle);

```
_vehicles[0] = _firstTruck;
```

is the line where it is wrong.
So I will make _vehicles[0] of type Truck.

```
Truck _vehicles[0]=new Truck("","","",0,0);
```

and then just add

```
_vehicles[0] = _firstTruck;
```

Is my assumption good?

Also, in the teacher's notes I see that I should do this :

```
_vehicles[0] = new Object();
```

Can someone explain this ?

Comment: Is Truck a subclass of Vehicle, or is it not? That is key information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array can be only of one type. If truck is not a subclass of vehicle, you are not going to be able to add all of those objects to the same array. However, if class truck "extends" vehicle, you should be able to add all those objects provided the array is of type vehicle.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I created the class Vehicle and the extended class Truck and works.